# node mysql query after crypto decrypt

Tags: javascript, mysql, asynchronous

```
var crypto = require('crypto'); <-- standart
var mysql = require('mysql'); <-- standart

var decrypt = function (encryptedMessage) {
    var decryptor = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc','somepass', 'somevector');
    decryptor.setAutoPadding(false);
    return decryptor.update(encryptedMessage, 'hex', 'utf8') + decryptor.final('utf8');
};

var dec = decrypt(someencryptedmessage);
console.log(dec); <-- working as expected
connection.query("UPDATE table SET some_column = 1 WHERE id = '" + dec + "'");
//Query sent like this UPDATE table SET some_column = 1 WHERE id = ''
```

So I think that problem in async race or something. How can I fix this ? Thanks.

Comment: At first glance it looks okay, but try [escaping `dec`](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values).

Comment: `connection.query("UPDATE table SET some_column = 1 WHERE id = '" + dec + "'");` **NEVER do this!** It's very dangerous. Instead, [use `?` to escape values](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-values), like this: `connection.query("UPDATE table SET some_column = 1 WHERE id = ?", [ dec ]);`

Comment: where does connection come from...?

Comment: Nope, same result. Connection is OK (sorry maybe this is rude answer). I have stable program and today decided to encrypt some values that was working in the same way as above and for long time was working without any problems. So escaping didn't help. dec variable - consist of 9 numbers. id column - VARCHAR in db. I have tried to use callbacks and promises and nothing helps. I spent half of the day and can't fix this up ) I have strong feeling that query fires too fast. I also tried setTimeout for query - nothing.

Comment: You probably have to post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of only some parts of your code, there's nothing inherently wrong with what you posted (aside from passing an unescaped value, which is a bit mitigated by it being encrypted with a, what I assume, secret key that you control).

Comment: It's something with encoding I guess. I tried this: if(dec == "encryptednumbersasstring"){console.log("They are the same");} And this if didn't work. But they print out the same. wtf

Comment: and the length of the decoded string 32 while original 17 )

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. There was hidden special chars in string. I added this and now all is working.

```
var dec = decrypt(someencryptedmessage).replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "");
```